# Go to specific tab from push notification

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, tabs, selectedindex

I have a piece of code which I don't know how to modify so that I go to a specific tab (TabIndex 3) from a push notification.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        var resultOK: Bool = false
        var result:UIBackgroundFetchResult = .noData

        prepareUserInfo(userInfo: userInfo) { (isOK) in
            resultOK = isOK
        }

        loadIncomingNotifications(application: application) { (isOK) in
            if isOK || resultOK {
                result = .newData
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! TabController
                    navigationController.selectedIndex = (navigationController.viewControllers?.count)! - 2
                }
            }
            completionHandler(result)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Change selected index value; navigationController.selectedIndex = 3

Comment: Tried it - no effect.

Comment: Just solved it myself

Comment: completionHandler()
        }
        
         let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! TabController
            navigationController.selectedIndex = 3
    }